# archive functionality for magento aw_blog extension

Tags: magento-1.7, blogs, archive

I have been working with a client who wanted a blog in the magento website. After installing the AW blog extension i realized that it doesn't have archive functionality, and i didn't find any solution in the web.

After few days of work, I have finally found a solution for this task. I didn't know where to post it, and I thought that this is the best place to share it.

I know that people usually don't post answers here, but I have to share, because out there, somebody is having difficult time, or might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will presume that you already installed the AW Blog extension to your magento project. [blog extension page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blog-community-edition.html)

1) first of all we need a placeholder for future datepicker. I choose the sidebar of AW_blog extension: **app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME\default\template\aw_blog\menu.phtml**

I added following html markup almost to the end:

```
<div class="block-content">
    <div class="menu-recent">
        <h5 class="uppercase"><?php echo Mage::helper('blog')->__('Archives'); ?></h5>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

2) After this i added jquery ui datepicker into project. we will need it for date selection. [jquery ui page](http://jqueryui.com/download/). Here I need make some note. I only copied the jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui.css, images folder with theme icons. I did this because i didn't need anything else. you can download everything if you want, but the key files are jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui.css, images folder.

a) copy *jquery-ui.js* into **skin\js** directory

b) copy *jquery-ui.css* and *images* folder into **skin\frontend\YOUR_THEME\default\css** directory

3) Add following code to **app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\page.xml**

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            ....
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery-ui.js</script></action>
            ...
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jquery-ui.css</stylesheet></action>
```

4) add following code to **app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME\default\template\page\head.phtml**
this is just simple work with datepicker plugin

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            window.location = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>news/?date='+dateText;//refreshes screen
        }
    });
});
```

all these four 4 steps are for frontend stuff. now we will go to the backend programming

1) open **app\code\community\AW\Blog\Block\blog.php** and replace getPosts() function with following code

```
public function getPosts()
{
    $collection = parent::_prepareCollection();

    $tag = $this->getRequest()->getParam('tag');
$date = $this->getRequest()->getParam('date');//gets $_GET[date] parameter

    if ($tag) {
        $collection->addTagFilter(urldecode($tag));
    }
else if ($date) { // checks if $date parameter exists
        $collection->addDateFilter(urldecode($date));
    }
    parent::_processCollection($collection);

    return $collection;
}
```

2) open **app\code\community\AW\Blog\Model\Mysql4\Blog\Collection.php** and add following function

```
public function addDateFilter($date) {
    if ($date = trim($date)) {
        $whereString = sprintf("main_table.created_time >= %s", $this->getConnection()->quote($date));
        $this->getSelect()->where($whereString);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This is it guys. If you need any help, just let me know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: used your code...approciate this...but it leads me to 404 page when select date...can you rply on this?

Comment: from the 4) step. window.location = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>news/?date='+dateText;//refreshes screen. you can see that i am using, 'news' url for news page (ex: http://mysite.com/news). i think probably you have something different. make sure to change 'news' string

Comment: hi, can i get archive without datepicker.  like month and year list archive. please suggest your answer.

Comment: @ravipatel i didn't understood what do you mean with 'month and year list archive'. maybe url might help. forexample.com/index.php/news/?date=2014-02-19. as you can see date has some values. you can just change the year and month numbers

Comment: error in app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\page.xml file..please give solution

Answer (score 1):

for month and year list archive

```
public function addDateFilter($date) {
if ($date = trim($date)) {
    $whereString = sprintf(
    "main_table.created_time = %s OR main_table.created_time LIKE %s OR main_table.created_time LIKE %s ", 
        $this->getConnection()->quote($date), $this->getConnection()->quote($date . '-%'),
        $this->getConnection()->quote('%-' . $date),$this->getConnection()->quote('%-' . $date . '-%')
        );
    $this->getSelect()->where($whereString);
}

return $this;
}
```

Examples:
`foo.com/index.php/news/?date=2014` or `bar.com/index.php/news/?date=2014-02`